# Подключение веб-сайта к удалённому серверу

Tags: php, python, сокет

Есть сервер который выполняет основную работу в виде обработки данных (python) и есть веб сайт на хостинге(php), 
который должен покдлючаться к этому серверу, передавать запрос и получать данные. 
Пробовал через сокеты, но запросы выполняются часто (каждые 2 секунды), т.е. для каждого запроса нужно устанавливать соединение. Но при большом кол-ве посетителей это становится проблемой.

Какие есть ещё варианты организовать подключение веб сайта к удалённому серверу?

Comment: Никакие, очевидно. Подключение к серверу означает установку соединения в том или ином виде. Каждые 2 секунды — это очень редко, нагруженные сервисы держат тысячи соединений в секунду, и ничего, работают. Вы лучше возникающие проблемы опишите более конкретно.

Comment: если данные не часто обновляются - кешировать ответы

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал реализовать api посредством post и json [тут что и как](https://mkdev.me/posts/chto-takoe-api-v-veb-prilozheniyah-i-zachem-on-nuzhen).